# Quickly apply specified font using keyboard shortcut in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, fonts

Is there a way I can create a keyboard shortcut in Microsoft Word (more of like a Macro or something) so I can quickly select some text and apply a specific font?

I am doing a lot of assignments where I need to write answers and then provide code for each answer too. I need to format the code using a font different from the normal text. But it is very tedious having to always select the text, scroll down the list to find that same font and click it. I am hoping I can setup a keyboard shortcut so I can somewhat automate that process.

Comment: Sure you can. Make a macro, assign it to a key.  Have you tried simply recording a macro of you setting the font yet?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to create a character style (as opposed to a paragraph style).

Then you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

You could also record a VBA macro as indicated by Techie007 but then you would have to manage the macro settings, security settings and so on.

The style and its shortcut can either be added to normal.dot for use in any document on that PC (probably best in this case) or in the document itself or in a template you use to create other documents.

Create a new style, change the type from paragraph to character, set the style you want & where you want to keep the style. Then click on the format button to get the dropdown. Choose Shortcut Key... and select an appropriate key combination and where you want to store it.